# Adjust line numbers in error messages

Tags: errors, sweave

## Question

Is there any way I can alter the line-numbers reported by TeX and friends in error messages?

This is almost an identical question to [Add offset to line number (in error message) when using input files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47861/add-offset-to-line-number-in-error-message-when-using-input-files), but the solution there (that LaTeX already treats `\input` properly) is not helpful for my problem.

I am programmatically generating (using a [custom python version](https://bitbucket.org/mforbes/pweave/wiki/Home) of [Sweave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweave)) `.tex` files from a different `.Plw` source file that inserts generated figures, source code etc.  As a result, when LaTeX complains, it refers to lines numbers in the generated `.tex` file rather then the `.Plw` file that I am editing.  Is there anyway I can insert something into the generated `.tex` file to instruct TeX that the line `x` in `.tex` is actually line `y` in the `.Plw` file?

The specific problem is simply a matter of offsets: each time a figure, or source code listing is inserted into the file, the current offset changes – it can go up or down – but all the other lines are copied verbatim with the same wrapping etc. as in the original `.Plw` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is absolutely correct (it is a matter of offsets). Sweave has the option `concordance=TRUE/FALSE` to control whether to write a "concordance file" which contains the offset information. However, the error navigation has never really been done in the past 10(?) years.

Recently [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org) tackled this problem and implemented both error navigation and `PDF <--> Rnw` synchronization based on this concordance information. You can download the [preview version](http://www.rstudio.org/download/preview) to test it out.

Also FYI, I wrote an R package named [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr) which is an alternative to Sweave. I looked at Pweave and it seems some of its features are also in `knitr`. RStudio also supports `knitr`, which means error navigation also works with `knitr`.

Comment: Writing a concordance file is a good idea so that external tools can do the translation (and might work for me as I ultimately use emacs, which I can probably train to use the concordance information).  I would still like to know if there is some way to coax TeX to use this information, so I will leave this question unanswered for a while.