# An equivalent of -file-line-error for warnings

Tags: errors

The `-file-line-error` command line flag for `tex`, `latex`, etc., is very effective. When you have a large project with plenty of files, the error message indicates very clearly not only the line number, but also the *name* of the file in which it occurred.

Unfortunately, this flag does nothing for warnings. What's the most effective way to find the name of the file in which under- or over- full warnings occur? Ideally, this could be done without resorting to an IDE.

The answers provided to the following questions are neat and related:

- [How to find the error line in a multi file document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142549/how-to-find-the-error-line-in-a-multi-file-document)
- [Warnings and errors highlighting when compiling in Bash environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84246/warnings-and-errors-highlighting-when-compiling-in-bash-environment)
- [How to easily determine the full name of the latex file when a build error occurs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116173/how-to-easily-determine-the-full-name-of-the-latex-file-when-a-build-error-occur)
- [Adjust line numbers in error messages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51621/adjust-line-numbers-in-error-messages)

**Clarification**

The problem becomes difficult when you have several levels of nesting and large log files (mine range between 5,000 and 30,000 lines, with lots of mostly useless information.)

A file open in indicated in the log by `(filename`, while a file close is 
indicated by `)`. Now, suppose you have a main file which inputs  section files, each of which inputs several subsection files,  each of which inputs tables and figures.

Suppose that you see an overfull message in line 17,432 in your log file, which says that the error occurred at input line 182. You have two options:

- search for line 182 in all files that make your project
- do  a backward search in your log file, carefully balancing open and close parenthesis until you find which of the input files was active at line 17,432
  of the log file.

Here is an actual excerpt from my `.log` file. Note that there are many open and close parenthesis in it which are not related to file inclusion. Also observe that input line numbers are missing from the last message in this excerpt.

```
21983 LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size  not available
21984 (Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 21.
21985 
21986 Overfull \hbox (9.91599pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--22
21987 \T1/ptm/m/n/10 (\T1/ptm/b/n/10 N\T1/ptm/m/n/10 umber of \T1/ptm/b/n/10 I\T1/ptm
21988 /m/n/10 nstance \T1/ptm/b/n/10 V\T1/ptm/m/n/10 ariables), \T1/ptm/b/n/10 MTE  \
21989 T1/ptm/m/n/10 (\T1/ptm/b/n/10 M\T1/ptm/m/n/10 u\T1/ptm/b/n/10 t\T1/ptm/m/n/10 a
21990 bility (\T1/ptm/b/n/10 E\T1/ptm/m/n/10 xplicit)),
21991  []
21992 
21993 
21994 Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Comment: (never too late to the party) I happen to be the author of script that precisely does all the "backward search in your log file, carefully balancing open and close parenthesis" and then pretty-prints the errors and warnings on the console. give it a look: https://github.com/guillaumesalagnac/latex-compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@AndrewCashner's answer lead me to an answer that works for me.

1. Open the file with `vi`, `vim`, or `gvim`
2. Locate the warning (this should be easy)
3. Type `A)' to add an open parenthesis at the end of the current line in the log file.
4. The editor's `showmatch` function will take you to the line in the log file which presents *the file most recently referenced in the log file before the warning*.

Here is an AWK script that could help a bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
    word($i)
  print top()": " $0
}
function word(s) {
  if (s ~ /^[(][^()]+$/) 
    push(substr(s,2))
  else
    letters(s)
}
function letters(s, i) {
  for (i = 1; i <= length(s); i++)
    letter(substr(s,i,1))
}
function letter(s) {
  if (s == "(")
    push("");
  else if (s == ")")
    pop();
}
function push(s) { stack[++sp] = s; }
function pop() { return stack[sp--];} 
function top(j) {
  for (j = sp; j >0; j--)
    if (stack[j] != "" )
      return stack[j] ;
  print "Sorry; I got confused - not sure what can be done"
  exit 1
}
```

The script reads a `.log` file, and prints it to the standard output prefixing each log line with the name of the input file that generated it. Pipe the output through `grep` as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92699/find-errors-and-warnings-in-pdflatex-output-highlight-terminal-output/93749#93749) and you could get a reasonable approximation of 
`-file-line-error`.

The script tries to balance parentheses in the input so as to figure out the current active file name. However, if for some reason, TeX prints blurbs out text
with unbalanced parentheses, e.g.,

```
 Underfull \hbox (badness 2065) in paragraph at lines 69--70
 [][]\EU2/lmr/m/n/10 With \EU2/lmr/bx/n/10 pro-to-types \EU2/lmr/m/n/10 (object-
 based, but not object-
  []
```

the script is guaranteed to be confused.

HTH

Answer (score 6):

> What's the most effective way to find the name of the file in which
>   under- or over- full warnings occur?

Search the `.log` file for the string `erfull` (either in text editor or command-line tool). This will give you all the overfull and underfull box warnings. The warnings will tell you which lines in the source file the error came from, and the log file will also indicate which PDF page the error occurred on.

As you read through the log file you can see each inputted subfile as it is opened. The warnings that occur after each filename pertain to the line numbers in that file.

---

I have concocted a example to demonstrate this, which I hope will not be too confusing. The file below is structured like so:

- Main file includes `section.tex`

  - `section.tex` inputs `table1.tex`
  - `section.tex` inputs `subsection.tex`

    - `subsection.tex` inputs `table2.tex`

Both of the table files create egregious box overflows.

The first `erfull` warning in the main `.log` file is this:

```
  (./section.tex (./table1.tex)
Overfull \hbox (3524.03448pt too wide in paragraph at lines 12-11
```

Looking at the generated subfiles `section.tex` and `table1.tex`, we can see that the overfull `tabular` environment in `table1.tex` starts on line 12 of `table1.tex`. This is the source of the `12` at the beginning of the page range in the warning.

`table1` is input into `section.tex`, on line 11 of `section.tex`. This is the source of the `11` in the warning page range.

So the log message may be translated as follows:

> I opened the file `section.tex`. Then I input the file `table1.tex`. When I input the file, I found an overfull `\hbox` somewhere between line 12 of `table1.tex` and line 11 of `section.tex`.

So to answer your question, how to find the name of the file in which the under- or overfull box occurs, **it is in the file most recently referenced in the log file before the warning.**

---

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%***************************************
\begin{filecontents}{table1.tex}






\begin{tabular}{llll}
a & b & c & \lipsum[1]\\
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents}

%***************************************
\begin{filecontents}{table2.tex}


\begin{minipage}{1in}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{filecontents}

%***************************************
\begin{filecontents}{subsection}






\subsection{Minipage}




\input{table2}
\end{filecontents}

%***************************************
\begin{filecontents}{section.tex}

\section{Confusion}
a
b

\input{table1}

d
e
f

\clearpage
\input{subsection}

\end{filecontents}

%***************************************
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\include{section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, I can retrieve the line number, but not the name of the file in which the warning occurred.

Comment: Not true. If the error is in a file that is `\input` to the main document, the warning will occur just after the log file shows that file being input.

Comment: OK, will edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: I suppose I am basically saying that your option #2 is the answer.

Comment: My log files do not contain any occureces of  `erfull`. Using pdflatex from TeXLive 2019.

Comment: @MaxPowers That should mean you don't have overfull or underfull boxes.